# Don't fully understand custom-written 'memcpy' function in C

Tags: c, utility-method

So I was browsing the Quake engine source code earlier today and stumbled upon some written utility functions. One of them was 'Q_memcpy':

```
void Q_memcpy (void *dest, void *src, int count)
{
    int             i;

    if (( ( (long)dest | (long)src | count) & 3) == 0 )
    {
        count>>=2;
        for (i=0 ; i<count ; i++)
            ((int *)dest)[i] = ((int *)src)[i];
    }
    else
        for (i=0 ; i<count ; i++)
            ((byte *)dest)[i] = ((byte *)src)[i];
}
```

I understand the whole premise of the function but I don't quite understand the reason for the bitwise OR between the source and destination address. So the sum of my questions are as follows:

- Why does 'count' get used in the same bitwise arithmetic?
- Why is that result's last two bits checked if they are differing?
- What purpose does this whole check serve?

I'm sure it's something obvious but please excuse my ignorance because I haven't really delved into the more low level side of things when it comes to programming. I just find it interesting and want to learn more.

Comment: it is important to understand that `count & 3` is a test to see if the variable `count` is divisible by 4.  Similarly, `count & 7` would test to see if it is divisible by 8, and so on.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Thank you for the feedback either way! I will keep this in mind from now on.

Comment: @bruceg And even more important to understand that it will only work to test divisibility with powers of 2...

Comment: Yes, I understood that @EugeneSh. The bitwise OR operations were confusing me a bit as well, but I got it! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes... `count & 12` doesn't do a very good job of checking divisibility by 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It first tests if **all 3 arguments** are divisible by 4. If - and only if - they all are, it proceeds with copying 4 bytes at a time.

I.e. this undecoded would be

```
if ((long) src % 4 == 0 && (long) dst % 4 == 0 && count % 4 == 0 )
{
    count = count / 4;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        ((int *)dest)[i] = ((int *)src)[i];
}
```

I am not sure if they tested their compiler and it generated bad code for even a test, and therefore they decided to write it in such a convoluted way. In any case, the `x | y | z` will guarantee that a bit *n* is set in the result if it is set in any of `x`, `y` or `z`. Therefore if the `(x | y | z) & 3` results in 0, none of the numbers had either of the 2 lowest bits set, and therefore are divisible by 4.

---

Of course it would be rather silly to use *now* - the standard library `memcpy` in recent library implementations is almost certainly better than this.

Therefore, on recent compilers you can **optimize** all calls to `Q_memcpy` by switching them to `memcpy`. GCC could generate things like 64-bit or SIMD moves with `memcpy` depending on the size of area to be copied.

Comment: Well, to "optimize" here we can combine the two methods. Copy the 4-byte aligned portion as `int`s, and the "corners" as bytes. Update: Actually no... If source and destination are mutually misalligned - we can't.

Comment: I am ready to accept this as an answer. Awesome explanation! The last sentence really made me go: "OOOHHH, I see!". Just one more question. Isn't the third line of your code supposed to be: count = count / 4

Comment: @SimeonLaplev yes, fixed

Answer (score 3):

It is finding out whether the source and destination pointers are `int` aligned, and whether the `count` is an exact `int` size of bytes.

If those three things are all true, the l.s. 2 bits of them all will be `0` (assuming pointers and `int` are 4 bytes). So the algorithm ORs the three values, and isolates the l.s. 2 bits.

In this case, it copies `int` by `int`. Otherwise it copies `char` by `char`.

If the test fails, a more sophisticated algorithm would copy some of the leading and trailing bytes `char` by `char` and the intermediate bytes `int` by `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The bitwise ORing and ANding with 3 is to check whether the source, destination and `count` are divisible by 4. If they are, the operation can work with 4-byte words, while this code is assuming `int` as 4 bytes. Otherwise the operation is performed bytewise.